# How to simplify php code that checks for null and sets value to replace null?

Tags: php

I have to write a lot of code like this:

```
         if ( !empty($value['fax'])) {
                $temp['fax'] = $value['fax'];
         } else {
            $temp['fax'] = "unknown";
         }
```

just wondering if there's a shorter version of this ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the ternary operators:

```
$temp['fax'] = !empty($value['fax']) ? $value['fax'] : 'unknown'
```

Comment: I think you've mixed up the $temp with the $value.

Comment: Yep. Fixed. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Check out the [Ternary Operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary):

```
$temp['fax'] = (!empty($value['fax'])) ? $value['fax'] : 'unknown';
```

If you're actually checking `isset()` or `is_null()` and not `empty()` (which includes `null`, `false`, `0`, `''`) then in PHP 7:

```
$temp['fax'] = $value['fax'] ?? 'unknown';
```

Comment: You can't use `?:` here like this, because if the condition is true it will use the returned value from `!empty($value['fax'])` which will be TRUE or FALSE and not the value of the variable.

Comment: Yeah, caught that.  Bonehead mistake.

Answer (score 2):

PHP7+ solution ([Null coalesce operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.coalesce)):

```
$temp['fax'] = $value['fax'] ?? 'unknown';
```